# gvim remote tab with command possible?

Tags: asynchronous, makefile, vim

The simplified version of my question is how can I achieve a command such as the following.

```
gvim --remote-tab-silent -c mak
```

When I run this command I am hoping for a new tab to be opened, and to have the make command run. What actually happens however is there are two new tabs "-c" and "mak"

Is there a way to do this? My end goal is to be able to within vim run a command such as this to give me asynchonous make output.

```
!gvim --remote-tab-silent -c mak
```

Thanks in advance.

**--EDIT--**
I found the documentation for --remote, which explains how to do a remote command with opening a file. The syntax applies to remote-tab apparently.

To do what I want I am now using

```
gvim --remote-tab-silent +mak MakeOutput
```

Similarly inside vim I can use

> !gvim --remote-tab-silent +mak
>   MakeOutput

It automatically opens the first error in a file for me, which is convenient I would think :)

Comment: My solution is still blocking however. If anyone knows how to make it asynchronous that would be even better.

Comment: Vim is not able to run anything asynchronously. Some enthusiasts are working on adding some asynchronous features, but they are far from being pulled into mainstream.

Comment: Using `+` instead of `-c` didn't change anything in gvim 7.4 :-( Where is the documentation for `--remote` that you mention? `man gvim` and `gvim --help` didn't say much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send commands to gvim when using --remote?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311254/how-to-send-commands-to-gvim-when-using-remote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you're asking is how to execute commands asynchronously with updates when they complete.

Have a look at my [AsyncCommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3431) plugin. It's just wraps the vim syntax required to execute something and load it with --remote. I've uploaded AsyncCommand 2.0 that includes an `AsyncMake` command.

Add the script to your `.vim/plugin` and you can build with `:AsyncMake` or `:AsyncMake target`. Errors will be opened in your quickfix once the make completes.