# How to send commands to gvim when using --remote?

Tags: vim, pipe

I want to look at the output of a command in a GVim window that's already opened.

To look at the output of a command in a new GVim window, I'd do:

```
mycommand | gvim -
```

To open a file an existing window, I'd do:

```
gvim --remote-silent myfile
```

How do I use them together? `mycommand | gvim --remote-silent -` does **not** work (it thinks `-` is a file in the current directory).

Answer (score 2):

Try `gvim --remote-silent <(mycommand)`.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have Gvim running with default servername `GVIM`, here's a command to execute `:echo 'It works!'` in the running Gvim:

```
vim --servername GVIM --remote-send ":echo 'It works!'<CR>"
```

This command returns nothing, it just sends "`:echo 'It works!'<CR>`" to the server and returns immediately.

If you need to evalute an expression and get the result, you might use this command:

```
vim --servername GVIM --remote-expr "version"
```

(version number will be returned)

```
vim --servername GVIM --remote-expr "2+2"
```

("4" will be returned)

Of course, you can declare your own function in Vim and use it as a expression, just like that:

```
vim --servername GVIM --remote-expr "MyOwnFunction()"
```